# Looping through a block of text using a keyword in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a text file with hundreds of thousands of lines. It's just a big dump of things.

Each new entry of the "things" starts with the same line, let's use `Name:` as an example.

I want to loop through each "thing" starting with `Name:` and ending with the next `Name:` as if it were an individual block of data. Some pseudo-code would be:

```
ForEach ($block-starting-with-"Name:"){
    #stuff and logic
}
```

What I have so far grabs test data, and splits the lines,

```
$content = Get-Content -Path "U:\Dump\test2.nmap"
$content = $content -split "`r`n"
ForEach ($line in $content){
    Write-host $line
}
```

I'm learning powershell to do some cool stuff at work.

**Sample Input**

```
Name: Tree
OS: Windows
Version: 8
Type: R
Top Speed: 11

Name: D20
Surname: Dice
OS: Pile of rocks
Version: 1
Color: Red
Is Rigged: Possibly
Are you just trying to inflate data for variance: Yes
Type: Yes

Name: Batman
OS: Justice
Type: Weird

Irrelevant data with line break to make things difficult
Because life is never easy

Name: Super Nintendo
OS: Android
Version: -10
Favorite Game: Call of Duty
Type: Gray

Name: Taverns Caramints
Slogan: Great British Sweets
Est: 1904
OS: All Natural Colors and Flavors
Version: 200 grams
Type: Delicious

Name: Hair Brush
OS: Yes
Version: Regular
Sitting on: my desk
Type: Brush

Name: Dell monitor
OS: Who knows
Version: decent
Type: 1920x1080
Refresh Rate: shite

Name: Sticky note pad
OS: Papyrus
Version: N/A
Type: Pink
Shape: square
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/479a8e38-f9b8-4716-9343-acb1ce9ad925/powershell-split-file-at-a-word?forum=winserverpowershell) shows a solution on the TechNet website. I'm not sure exactly what you want the output to bed but you could do something like this:

```
$content = Get-Content -Path C:\Path\To\File.txt -Raw

$content -split '(?m)(?=^Name:)' | Foreach-Object {
    Write-Host $_
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
Name: Tree
OS: Windows
Version: 8
Type: R
Top Speed: 11
```

```
Name: D20
Sur
Dice
OS: Pile of rocks
Version: 1
Color: Red
Is Rigged: Possibly
Are you just trying to inflate data for variance: Yes
Type: Yes
```

```
Name: Batman
OS: Justice
Type: Weird

Irrelevant data with line break to make things difficult
Because life is never easy
```

```
Name: Super Nintendo
OS: Android
Version: -10
Favorite Game: Call of Duty
Type: Gray
```

```
Name: Taverns Caramints
Slogan: Great British Sweets
Est: 1904
OS: All Natural Colors and Flavors
Version: 200 grams
Type: Delicious
```

```
Name: Hair Brush
OS: Yes
Version: Regular
Sitting on: my desk
Type: Brush
```

```
Name: Dell monitor
OS: Who knows
Version: decent
Type: 1920x1080
Refresh Rate: shite
```

```
Name: Sticky note pad
OS: Papyrus
Version: N/A
Type: Pink
Shape: square
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I see! So "split" can really be anything I want.

I was confused when, in my research, I saw the variable $line came out of nowhere but intuitively was able to get assigned to each line.

Where can I learn about these "pre defined" variables, or arguments like what you showed me?

Comment: Use `-split '(?m)(?=^Name:)'` to a) preserve the string "Name:" and b) only split at lines beginning with "Name:".

Comment: I have updated my answer to include @AnsgarWiechers comment :-)

Comment: @Ghawblin You can see a full guide on PowerShell punctuation [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/the-complete-guide-to-powershell-punctuation/)

Comment: @I.TDelinquent, you're an absolute gem. I love it when people teach me, not just tell me the answers. I will use your thoughts to better myself. Thank you so much!

Comment: @I.TDelinquent, dumb question. When we say "ForEach-Object", specifically the "Object" part, how is that working? What is the object? Is it a variable I can assign? Does it dynamically create an array and each element of $content is added to that array? I know what a ForEach loop is, but I'm not certain what the implied object is :c!

Comment: `ForEach-Object` is a cmdlet for use in pipelines, as opposed to `foreach` loops, which cannot be used in pipelines. [See here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/getting-to-know-foreach-and-foreach-object/). To confuse people Microsoft threw in a gratuitous default alias `foreach` for the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet when they released Powershell.